# Changing switch variable inside a case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

In the following code:

```
int i = 0;

switch(i)
{
    case 0:
        cout << "In 0" << endl;
        i = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        cout << "In 1" << endl;
        break;
}
```

What will happen? Will it invoke undefined behavior?

Comment: Why would it? If you're expecting `case 1` to be executed since you changed `i` to 1, that won't happen either since execution will reach the end of the `switch` statement once the `break` at the end of `case 0` is encountered.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No undefined behavior.  But the value of `i` is only tested when the code reaches `switch (i)`.  So `case 1:` will be skipped (by the `break;` statement).

The `switch` keyword does not mean "run code whenever the value of `i` is 0 / 1".  It means, check what `i` is RIGHT NOW and run code based on that.  It doesn't care what happens to `i` in the future.

In fact, it's sometimes useful to do:

```
for( step = 0; !cancelled; ++step ) {
    switch (step)
    {
        case 0:
            //start processing;
            break;

        case 1:
            // more processing;
            break;

        case 19:
            // all done
            return;
    }
}
```

And changing the control variable inside a `case` block is extremely common when building a finite state machine (although not required, because you could set `next_state` inside the `case`, and do the assignment `state = next_state` afterward).

Answer (score 1):

You **break** out of this switch statement after you set it to 1 which is defined behavior so it will never enter `case 1`.

Comment: The behavior would still be well defined (but different) without the `break`.

Comment: Yes it would, it would then fall through and print both, with no relation to the fact that next value is case 1.

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue here. The expression in the switch condition is evaluated when it is reached. It doesn't have to be a variable and if it is the variable can be subsequently modified without any effect on the behaviour of the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your output would be :

"In 0"

even if you assign the value i = 1 it wont be reflected because switch does not operate in iteration, it is one time selection as break would make it go out of the switch statement.