# Change the switch statement key in a case, allowed?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

Will it work/is it allowed to have a switch-case statement and change the key in a statement?

For example:

```
temp = 1

switch(temp)
{
    case 1:
         temp = 2;
         //Do something with temp..
    break;
}
```

The point of doing this is just that I don't have to create another variable, and it also makes sense to do so in my program. I am not asking about changing to another case in the switch-case statement, just if it's allowed to reuse the variable used as the key without any side effects.

Comment: Yes, it will work as expected.

Comment: You can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333701/changing-switch-variable-inside-a-case

Comment: There is no point in your point. Just create another variable. It will not hurt and it makes your code clearer to read and understand for others. Leave the details to your compiler.

Comment: That will work but you **should** almost certainly create another variable. You seem to be reusing one – but there’s an endless supply, so no need to skimp on them. Almost all variables should be considered (or actually made) `const`. (Edit: big exception to this rule: state machines, as several answers have pointed out. How could I have forgotten this?)

Comment: I am parsing a message and it would make the code less readable using more variables. See the answer by Tim Cas.

Comment: A switch is just a binary search for the case and a jump to the code.  Once the jump is finished the switch statement has no further effect so changing the variable is fine.  I do this a lot in embedded systems: at the end of the case set the switch variable to the value of the next case and exit the function so that when it is called again later it will start again where it left off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you may do that. In fact, the following is common practice for writing [lexers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis):

```
int c = getc(file);
switch(c)
{
case '+':
    c = getc(file); // < `c` modified here!
    switch(c)
    {
    case '+': return OP_INC;
    default: ungetc(c, file); return OP_ADD;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I am doing and it makes sense to reuse the same variable instead of having several (which in my mind makes the code less understandable, despite a lot of people commenting the opposite on this question).

Comment: In that case, do reuse! You didn't really provide a context, so people just thought that you were trying to reuse the variable for a completely different purpose (which is considered bad practice).

Comment: I agree, but people tend to not answer the question asked as it is. I only asked if it was legal, not a good way to do it ;) Will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to.

Answer (score 4):

This is perfectly fine. Virtually every state machine on the planet does something equivalent to what you do here.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not a good idea to use the same variable however the code will work because the branch is determined in the moment when the expression in the switch statement is evaluated.

Comment: It isn't undefined behaviour.  Why is it not a good idea?

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah Sometimes such a code confuses readers.